# Woocommerce calculate shipping fee after added discounts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Hi i'm looking for the action which triggered before the shipping fee calculation.

I have the following function, but this one runs after the shipping fee calculation. The problem is that in this site, you get discounts if you buy more than 3, 5 or 10 items, and the shipping is based on the price of your cart total. But if i select 3 items (so it gets a discount) and because of this price will go below the minimum price for the shipping method but the shipping method wont change'.

```
    add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
    function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
        if( $cart->cart_contents_count >= 3 && $cart->cart_contents_count <= 4 ){
            // Calculate the amount to reduce
            $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.1;  
            $cart->add_fee( 'Text', -$discount);
            return;
        }

        if( $cart->cart_contents_count >= 5 && $cart->cart_contents_count < 10 ){
            // Calculate the amount to reduce
            $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.15;
            $cart->add_fee( 'Text', -$discount);
            return;
        }

        if( $cart->cart_contents_count >= 10 ){
            // Calculate the amount to reduce
            $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.2;
            $cart->add_fee( 'Text', -$discount);
            return;
        }
    }
```

As you can see the current action I'm using is this one: `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`

thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this hook **"woocommerce_calculate_totals"**, as it will trigger before calculation so that you may do your own calculation and can add your fee accordingly.